# Hide child of parent categories already hidden with "get_terms_args" - Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, arguments, wp-list-categories

I would need your help as I am unable to hide subcategories, or rather, child categories of already hidden and defined categories.
I tried entering `$args['parent'] = 0;` but it hides all the parent categories. I've also tried `$args['exclude_tree']`, but for some unknown reason, it crashes and won't let me move on.
I would be grateful if someone could help me out.

This is the function:

```
add_filter( 'get_terms_args', 'mamaduka_edit_get_terms_args', 10, 2 );

/**
* Exclude product categories from Woocommerce
*/

function mamaduka_edit_get_terms_args( $args, $taxonomies ) {
 //print_r($taxonomies);
 //print_r($args);
if ( is_admin() && 'product_cat' !== $taxonomies )
    return $args;

$args['exclude'] = [50, 22, 20, 31, 35, 45, 40, 65, 37, 40, 3434]; // Array of cat ids you want to exclude
$args['parent'] = 0;
return $args;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like `exclude_tree` would be the easiest option here, so you should go and investigate _why_ it "crashes."

Comment: I tried. This is the warning: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)

Comment: That sounds like it is probably "running in circles" at some point, so I would check your database content, whether the relationship between all parents and children is actually set properly.

Comment: If you got this warning "Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)"  then try to increase the memory limit in your config file.

Comment: There are some parent categories and some subcategories in the array. The database is set up correctly...
I can't figure it out....

Comment: I tried changing the memory_limit to 1G but nothing

Comment: what is the purpose of hiding categories and in which place do you want these categories to be hidden?

Comment: @VijayHardaha In the entire e-commerce.  With that function above, those categories declared via id lead to a 404 error and that's exactly what I want.  But I would like the sub categories of those declared category ids to be hidden.